# How to detect selected row in sapui 5 Table and get data from it?

Tags: javascript, uitableview, sapui5

Is there any way to detect when I select a row in a dynamic SingleSelect Mode sapui 5 Table?

Could be by using an event or something similar?

The thing is... I kind of new using this technology.

Here is how I am trying to do right now:

```
    var oTabla = new sap.m.Table("tableId",{
        mode: "SingleSelect",
        columns: [{
            hAlign: 'Center',
            header: new Text({
                text: "N° Cuotas"
            })
        }, {
            hAlign: 'Center',
            header: new Text({
                text: "Código Autorización"
            })
        }, {
            hAlign: 'Center',
            header: new Text({
                text: "Monto (UF) "
            })
        }, {
            hAlign: 'Center',
            header: new Text({
                text: "Monto ($) "
            })
        }]
    });
```

This table is dynamically created.

And here is how I'm trying to get the data:

```
  var oItem= this.byId("tableId").getSelectedItem();
            alert(oItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Table control inherits from ListBase which has an event called **selectionChange**
You can use this event.

```
var oTabla = new sap.m.Table("tableId",{
    mode: "SingleSelect",
    selectionChange: function(oEvent){
      // handle the selectionChange event
    }
    columns: [{
        hAlign: 'Center',
        header: new Text({
            text: "N° Cuotas"
        })
    }, {
        hAlign: 'Center',
        header: new Text({
            text: "Código Autorización"
        })
    }, {
        hAlign: 'Center',
        header: new Text({
            text: "Monto (UF) "
        })
    }, {
        hAlign: 'Center',
        header: new Text({
            text: "Monto ($) "
        })
    }]
});
```